# SSRS Count indicators active

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, ms-reports

I am writing a report where I have an indicator determined if a person is under a percentage for a certain category of orders. If the person is below threshold, then a big X is displayed by the percentage.

Outside of the group I am looking to put a red flag within the same column for the week to show that if there is at least one X for a category, then this red flag will display.

Mainly I am using this because there are a lot of drop down lists within the report and it will be easier to view if a red flag is displayed instead of a bunch of X's.

Thus, my question: is it possible to select an indicator within a child group in an expression?

Comment: In order to help you share a sample of your data and expected results

Comment: I just checked with a supervisor. We will not need to implement this, so I will be deleting this post. Thank you for viewing anyway.